# Image stretching from points

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, stretching, deep-fake

I have an image of a face, facial landmark positions of it:
[image]
And another image with the landmarks at other positions:
[image]
I need to stretch the first image by "dragging" the landmarks to the new positions which are in the second image, in Python (I'm trying to create a very basic deepfake).
How can I implement this? (I have the exact position of the landmarks)
I searched a lot in Google but haven't found any result, so I hoped someone here can help me.

Comment: I do not think this is doable without deep learning.

Comment: Really? There is no simple way to do this?

Comment: I don't think so. It is not a simple composition of translation and rotation: you are actually warping the image. Absolutely a non-trivial process.

Comment: In that case do you have any idea where to look for a solution?